# Arbitrary 2-forms on $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-forms

If I want to compute with arbitrary 2-forms on $\mathbb{R}^4$, I wonder if each form must contain all 4 variables e.g $x, y, z, t$.

If so, I figure that two-forms in 4 dimension will correspond to the multi-index $$I = \{(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4) \}.$$ That is a set of $$\binom{4}{2}$$  strictly increasing 2-tuples if I have understood correctly. Given that the definition of $k$-forms is $$\omega = \sum a_I dx_I,$$ I pick arbitrary elements from $I$ to form 2-forms. Example $$\omega = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_1 \wedge dx_3$$ and $$\tau = dx_2 \wedge dx_3 + dx_3 \wedge dx_4.$$

The wedge product $\omega \wedge \tau$ is trivial because each term contain $dx_i \wedge dx_i = 0$.

EDIT: Can I choose how many basis elements to include in the linear combinations i.e. the $k$-forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can certainly compute products like $\omega \wedge \tau = 0$ without all four indices appearing.

If you want $\alpha \wedge \beta \ne 0$ for 2-forms $\alpha, \beta$ on $4$-space, then you do, indeed, need to have all four indices appear somewhere -- two of them in $\alpha$ (and possibly in $\beta$ as well), and the complementary pair in $\beta$ (and possible in $\alpha$ as well). Even so, that won't guarantee that $\alpha \wedge \beta \ne 0$.

For instance, if 
$$
\alpha = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_3 \wedge dx_4\\
\beta = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 - dx_3 \wedge dx_4
$$
then we have $\alpha \wedge \beta = 0$, despite all four indices appearing.

Comment: Thanks! To be clear: you are saying that any 2-form in 4-space can contain anything from 1 to 4 variables?

Comment: NO NO NO!! In fact this is the symplectic $2$-form on $\Bbb R^4$, and $\alpha\wedge\beta$ is most definitely NOT $0$.

Comment: @G.Debailly: You can use as many or as few basis elements as you wish to make up your linear combination.

Comment: You're right, of course, Ted. Lord, I must be very tired. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks, @John. To G.Debailly, you should work out $\alpha\wedge\alpha$ very carefully and figure out why it's nonzero. This is actually a very important example.

Comment: oh, the luxury and privilege of Math StackExchange. @TedShifrin I will work that example straight away, thanks :)

Comment: By the way, @G.Debailly. I don't know what your background or ultimate goals are, but you might take a look at some of [my multivariable math lectures on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). There's a serious treatment of differential forms, integrals, Stokes's Theorem, etc., among other things.